# Firefox - Huge Cursor

Tags: firefox, text-cursor

I have a contentEditable div on which if a cursor is placed it's displayed as a huge cursor!

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body >
        <div style="position:absolute; top:2px; left:30px; right:0px; bottom: 0px; height:100%;">
            <div contentEditable="true" style=" color:#333333; height:100%; width:100%; cursor:text;" spellcheck="false"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/yW62h/

Here's what it looks like in my browser (FFX3.5)
[image]

This problem also appears in FFX3.6 and 4.0b6

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seeing as the cursor ceases to be huge as soon as there's any text at all in there, I'd say it looks like a browser bug.

Comment: This is funny. I'd point my finger at contentEditable=true & browser "bug" - whereas I wouldn't call it a bug, more an annoyance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Firefox bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537475 :(

Answer (score 1):

Not declaring 100% height and it works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/nS3X8/

Caret height is based on height in Firefox (which seems like a bug to me).
Though it based on line-height in Webkit.

When setting the height of an input element use padding instead of height and Firefox will behave.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `<br />` inside the editable div.
That worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/66A2h/